# python numpy exponentially spaced samples between a start and end value

Tags: python, numpy

`numpy.linspace` generates evenly spaced 
float samples between a start and end value.

```
print (numpy.linspace(0.0, 1.0, num=9))

# [0 0.125 0.25 0.375 0.5  0.625 0.75  0.875 1]

print (numpy.linspace(9000.0, 1000.0, num=9))

# [9000. 8000. 7000. 6000. 5000. 4000. 3000. 2000. 1000.]
```

How can I generate exponentially spaced samples between a start and end value ?

For example, to the power of 2:

```
[0. 0.016 0.0625 0.141 0.25 0.391 0.562 0.766 1.]
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the case of going between 0 and 1, you can just take the square of the array:

```
print (numpy.linspace(0.0, 1.0, num=9)**2 )
# [0. 0.016 0.0625 0.141 0.25 0.391 0.562 0.766 1.]
```

or

```
print (numpy.power(numpy.linspace(0.0, 1.0, num=9), 2) )
# [0. 0.016 0.0625 0.141 0.25 0.391 0.562 0.766 1.]
```

**Edit:**

A more generalized approach could be to 1) take the inverse power of the start and stop numbers, 2) get the linear spacing between those values, 3) return the array raised to the power.

```
import numpy as np

def powspace(start, stop, power, num):
    start = np.power(start, 1/float(power))
    stop = np.power(stop, 1/float(power))
    return np.power( np.linspace(start, stop, num=num), power) 

print( powspace(0, 1, 2, 9) )
# [0. 0.016 0.0625 0.141 0.25 0.391 0.562 0.766 1.]
```

Then you can go between any positive values.  For example, going from 9000 to 1000 with values spaced to the power of 3:

```
print( powspace(9000, 1000, 3, 9) )
# [9000. 7358.8 5930.4 4699.9 3652.6 2773.7 2048.5 1462.2 1000.]
```

Comment: Very nice. The [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html#numpy.logspace) show how they accomplish `np.logspace` via a similar technique.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `np.logspace` such that:

```
np.logspace(-9, 0, base=2, num=10)
```

which is [equivalent to](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) `power(base, y)`

**EDIT**

The answer mentions exponential spaced, then the squares of values.

This answer is actually exponential spaced, i.e. 2^x. The values x^2 is not exponential space, but polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

If you're ok with powers of 10, why not just:

```py
import numpy as np

def powspace(start: float, stop: float, num: int):
  log_start, log_stop = np.log(start), np.log(stop)
  return np.exp(np.linspace(log_start, log_stop, num))

>>> powspace(9000, 1000, 9)
>>> array([9000.        , 6838.52117086, 5196.15242271, 3948.22203886,
       3000.        , 2279.50705695, 1732.05080757, 1316.07401295,
       1000.        ])
```